# Can I stop the mouse from interacting with the intelliJ IDEA switcher?

Tags: intellij-idea, mouseevent, keyboard-shortcuts

I often switch between editors in intellJ with `Ctrl`-`Tab` and at the same time I accidentally move the mouse (which is sometimes over the switcher), which means I end up choosing a random editor rather than the one I wanted.

Is there any way I can prevent the switcher from reacting to mouse input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS and IDEA version do you use? I've tested with IDEA 10 on Windows and mouse events do not affect the Ctrl+Tab window at all.

If it still happens for you in the latest IDEA version, please file a bug with the steps to reproduce at: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA.

It's a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-26394) in IDEA versions before IDEA 10.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.1 (Lucid), and IDEA 9.0.4

Comment: I'm afraid it's a bug in IDEA 9 which was fixed in IDEA 10: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-26394. So the solution would be to upgrade. I've updated my reply.